# How do I automatically save Downloads to a Dropbox folder?

Tags: downloading, dropbox

The thing with the Dropbox internal folders is that Dropbox doesn't store its starred files as exact duplicates of the original file. So a starred PDF file on Dropbox isn't stored as a PDF file (although I haven't tried renaming it to see if it still works as a PDF).

I'd like to auto-save my PDF downloads to Dropbox so that when I annotate them, I'll be able to access them frictionlessly on my computer as well.

Comment: The dropbox folder does **not** sync so what's the point?

Comment: Actually it does sync. I know since I annotate the Dropbox PDFs I read on my tablet and I can see my annotations on my computer.

Comment: Is this behavior documented somewhere? It doesn't work for me if I put a random file into the folder.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik I get the same behavior if I open PDFs from the Android Dropbox App and annotate them. I think it's because the PDF was opened with Dropbox. If you just place a file within the Dropbox folder it won't get synced.

Comment: Yeah I use ezPDF